# How to handle InvalidKeyError in python

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm using msoffcrypto to do some task with excel files, I have a list of password , there is a correct password can open the file. my code is looping all the element in the list of password then try one by one. Code like below:

```
import io
import msoffcrypto
import openpyxl as xl
passwd = ['Welcome1','Welcome2','Welcome3']

decrypted_workbook = io.BytesIO()
with open(r'C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\test\Printer User list.xlsx', 'rb') as file:
    office_file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(file)
    for pword in passwd:
        office_file.load_key(password=pword)
        try:
            office_file.decrypt(decrypted_workbook)
        except KeyError as key:
            print(key)
```

I would like to capture which is invalid password and which is correct password. Tried with above code, it show the error below , could you please assist on this ?

InvalidKeyError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_21444/985138176.py in 
11         office_file.load_key(password=pword)
12         try:
---> 13             office_file.decrypt(decrypted_workbook)
14         except KeyError as key:
15             print(key)

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\msoffcrypto\format\ooxml.py in decrypt(self, ofile, verify_integrity)
    199         # If the file is successfully decrypted, there must be a valid OOXML file, i.e. a valid zip file
    200         if not zipfile.is_zipfile(io.BytesIO(obuf)):
--> 201             raise exceptions.InvalidKeyError("The file could not be decrypted with this password")
    202 
    203     def is_encrypted(self):

InvalidKeyError: The file could not be decrypted with this password
```

Comment: Have you tried catching `InvalidKeyError` instead of `KeyError`?

Comment: tried with  InvalidKeyError , it got the other " NameError: name 'InvalidKeyError' is not defined"

Comment: It sounds like `InvalidKeyError` may not have been imported. If you're using jwt, try something like `import InvalidKeyError from jwt.exceptions`

Comment: Sorry that would be `from jwt.exceptions import InvalidKeyError`

Comment: hi i have solved my issue already, i just use except: continue , it work as fine :D

Answer (score 0):

if error happen it will continue for loop, i tried with below then it could work for my porpose.

```
import io
import msoffcrypto
import openpyxl as xl
passwd = ['Welcome1','Welcome2','Welcome3']

decrypted_workbook = io.BytesIO()
with open(r'C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\test\Printer User list.xlsx', 'rb') as file:
    office_file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(file)
    for pword in passwd:
        office_file.load_key(password=pword)
        try:
            office_file.decrypt(decrypted_workbook)
        except KeyError as key:
            print(key)
```